# Black screen after boot

Tags: windows-8.1

Yesterday Windows installed some updates when shutting down. Today I wanted to start Windows, but after the BIOS screen I only see a black screen, with no cursor or whatsoever. I search for this issue and found out, that it might have something to do with a corrupt display driver. But this does not help my much because I can't enter the safe mode of Windows (hitting the F8 key has no effect). I also tried to recover from an old recovery point using the Windows 8.1 installation DVD, but I get a message that no recovery points were found even though I'm pretty sure I have some. What can I do at this point? Is re-installing Windows my only option?

**Edit:** I also tried to open up the task manager with Ctrl+Shift+Esc, but it also doesn't show up. I only get a message from my monitor "Suggested Resolution: 1920x1080px". I also saw yesterday a second before the shutdown an error message, but I wasn't able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the problem fixed itself. I turned the computer on and went away playing piano for about 45 minutes, afterwards I could login into the computer. In the event log I see the following entries:

- Incorrect block at device \Device\Harddisk0\DR0
- Error "1053" in DCOM as service "defragsvc" with arguments "not available" has been started to use the following server: {D20A3293-3341-4AE8-9AAF-8E397CB63C34}

(The entries are translated as my system doesn't run on English)